# Deploy Apache Beam multi-file job to Dataflow including protobufs

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to deploy an Apache Beam job which includes a proto definition (_pb2) to Google Dataflow, however I'm getting a pickling error:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'test_pb2.Example'>: import of module 'test_pb2' failed [while running 'Convert to Proto']
```

The structure of my project follows the suggested approach in [this document](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/), and the [juliaset example](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/juliaset):

```
root/
  main.py
  setup.py
  pipeline/
    __init__.py
    pipeline.py
    test_pb2.py
    input.txt
  proto/
    test.proto
```

test_pb2 is generated using protoc from test.proto and is used in a transform, to convert a dict to proto.

Content of main.py:

```
import logging

from pipeline import pipeline

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    pipeline.run()
```

Content of pipeline.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import apache_beam as beam
import argparse
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from google.protobuf import json_format

from pipeline import test_pb2


class TransformDictToProto(beam.DoFn):

    def process(self, row, **kwargs):
        d = dict({'identifier': row})
        result = json_format.ParseDict(d, test_pb2.Example())
        yield result


class ConvertProtoToJson(beam.DoFn):

    def process(self, row, **kwargs):
        yield json_format.MessageToJson(row)


def run(argv=None):
    """Run the workflow."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--input', default="pipeline/input.txt")
    parser.add_argument('--output', default="pipeline/output.txt")

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        lines = (p
                 | 'Read' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input)
                 | 'Convert to Proto' >> beam.ParDo(TransformDictToProto())
                 | 'Convert to Bytes' >> beam.ParDo(ConvertProtoToJson())
                 )

        lines | beam.io.WriteToText(known_args.output)
```

I would expect this to work both locally and on Google Dataflow. Possible directions I've been looking into are type hints on the custom ParDos, and type hints, but to no avail. Has anyone experienced something similar, or does anyone have seen a working apache beam pipeline on GCP including protobuf generated files?

This is the complete stacktrace I get for the above example:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/versions/research/bin/python /Users/kmevissen/src/private/beam_multifile_with_proto_example/main.py
/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/versions/research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/__init__.py:84: UserWarning: Some syntactic constructs of Python 3 are not yet fully supported by Apache Beam.
  'Some syntactic constructs of Python 3 are not yet fully supported by '
INFO:root:Missing pipeline option (runner). Executing pipeline using the default runner: DirectRunner.
INFO:root:==================== <function annotate_downstream_side_inputs at 0x110330320> ====================
INFO:root:==================== <function fix_side_input_pcoll_coders at 0x110330440> ====================
INFO:root:==================== <function lift_combiners at 0x1103304d0> ====================
INFO:root:==================== <function expand_sdf at 0x110330560> ====================
INFO:root:==================== <function expand_gbk at 0x1103305f0> ====================
INFO:root:==================== <function sink_flattens at 0x110330710> ====================
INFO:root:==================== <function greedily_fuse at 0x1103307a0> ====================
INFO:root:==================== <function read_to_impulse at 0x110330830> ====================
INFO:root:==================== <function impulse_to_input at 0x1103308c0> ====================
INFO:root:==================== <function inject_timer_pcollections at 0x110330a70> ====================
INFO:root:==================== <function sort_stages at 0x110330b00> ====================
INFO:root:==================== <function window_pcollection_coders at 0x110330b90> ====================
INFO:root:Running (((ref_AppliedPTransform_WriteToText/Write/WriteImpl/DoOnce/Read_10)+(ref_AppliedPTransform_WriteToText/Write/WriteImpl/InitializeWrite_11))+(ref_PCollection_PCollection_4/Write))+(ref_PCollection_PCollection_5/Write)
INFO:root:Running ((((((ref_AppliedPTransform_Read/Read_3)+(ref_AppliedPTransform_Convert to Proto_4))+(ref_AppliedPTransform_Convert to Bytes_5))+(ref_AppliedPTransform_WriteToText/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles_12))+(ref_AppliedPTransform_WriteToText/Write/WriteImpl/Pair_13))+(ref_AppliedPTransform_WriteToText/Write/WriteImpl/WindowInto(WindowIntoFn)_14))+(WriteToText/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Write)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 782, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 453, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 921, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 142, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 122, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.update_counters_start
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 196, in apache_beam.runners.worker.opcounters.OperationCounters.update_from
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 214, in apache_beam.runners.worker.opcounters.OperationCounters.do_sample
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1014, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1023, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 330, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.FastPrimitivesCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 385, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.FastPrimitivesCoderImpl.encode_to_stream
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 200, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.CallbackCoderImpl.encode_to_stream
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/versions/research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coders.py", line 594, in <lambda>
    lambda x: dumps(x, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL), pickle.loads)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'test_pb2.Example'>: import of module 'test_pb2' failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kmevissen/src/private/beam_multifile_with_proto_example/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    pipeline.run()
  File "/Users/kmevissen/src/private/beam_multifile_with_proto_example/pipeline/pipeline.py", line 43, in run
    bts | beam.io.WriteToText(known_args.output)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/versions/research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 426, in __exit__
    self.run().wait_until_finish()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/versions/research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 406, in run
    self._options).run(False)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/versions/research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 419, in run
    return self.runner.run_pipeline(self, self._options)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/versions/research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/direct_runner.py", line 128, in run_pipeline
    return runner.run_pipeline(pipeline, options)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/versions/research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner.py", line 294, in run_pipeline
    default_environment=self._default_environment))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/versions/research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner.py", line 301, in run_via_runner_api
    return self.run_stages(stage_context, stages)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/versions/research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner.py", line 383, in run_stages
    stage_context.safe_coders)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/versions/research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner.py", line 655, in _run_stage
    result, splits = bundle_manager.process_bundle(data_input, data_output)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/versions/research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner.py", line 1471, in process_bundle
    result_future = self._controller.control_handler.push(process_bundle_req)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/versions/research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner.py", line 990, in push
    response = self.worker.do_instruction(request)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/versions/research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 342, in do_instruction
    request.instruction_id)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/versions/research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 368, in process_bundle
    bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/versions/research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 593, in process_bundle
    data.ptransform_id].process_encoded(data.data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/versions/research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 143, in process_encoded
    self.output(decoded_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 255, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 256, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 143, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 428, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ImpulseReadOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 435, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ImpulseReadOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 256, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 143, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 593, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 594, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 778, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 784, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 851, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/versions/research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/future/utils/__init__.py", line 421, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 782, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 453, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 921, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 142, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 122, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.update_counters_start
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 196, in apache_beam.runners.worker.opcounters.OperationCounters.update_from
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 214, in apache_beam.runners.worker.opcounters.OperationCounters.do_sample
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1014, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1023, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 330, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.FastPrimitivesCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 385, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.FastPrimitivesCoderImpl.encode_to_stream
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 200, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.CallbackCoderImpl.encode_to_stream
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/versions/research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coders.py", line 594, in <lambda>
    lambda x: dumps(x, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL), pickle.loads)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'test_pb2.Example'>: import of module 'test_pb2' failed [while running 'Convert to Proto']

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Just to add, this pipeline is just an example to demonstrate the challenge I have on a more complicated pipeline, the functionality in the example is quite odd.

Comment: Sorry that it took a while. I'll take a look...

Comment: I couldn't repro this (single directory containing `test.proto`, (also `test_pb2.py`), `pipeline.py`, `input.txt`). This on Beam master. It may be that it is working now?

Comment: We have had to deal with pickling problems here and there. So that's why I think that it may have been fixed already.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue in beam 2.20.0, with a different proto.

Comment: Can confirm i have the same issue with beam 2.52.0